# Read ini sections with no values and append it to a dictionary

Tags: c#, ini

I have the following ini file with sections and keys but no values asigned:

```
[core]
bul_gravel_heli
ent_dst_concrete_large
bul_wood_splinter

[cut_armenian1]
cs_arm2_muz_smg
cs_ped_foot_dusty
```

What I want to do is:

- Read all the secions and vaues.
- Store them in a dictionary in the format:

`{section: {key1, key2, key3, key4, etc}`

Now the problem is that I can't find anywhere an example of ini file reading without values, all the results I've found are for reading ini files without sections.

- To give a brief of what I want to do with the stored dictionary is this:

  - There's a function `public void AddList(string listName, List<dynamic> list)` and for each one of the dictionary keys and values I want to create the method. I already know that I can use for loops but I'm stuck at parsing the ini file.

Comment: What have you tried that is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a simple `foreach` loop should do:

```
private static Dictionary<string, List<string>> IniToDictionary(IEnumerable<string> lines) {
  Dictionary<string, List<string>> result = 
    new Dictionary<string, List<string>>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

  string category = "";

  foreach (string line in lines) {
    string record = line.Trim();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(record) || record.StartsWith("#"))
      continue;
    else if (record.StartsWith("[") && record.EndsWith("]")) 
      category = record.Substring(1, record.Length - 2);
    else {
      int index = record.IndexOf('=');

      string name = index > 0 ? record.Substring(0, index) : record;

      if (result.TryGetValue(category, out List<string> list))
        list.Add(name);
      else
        result.Add(category, new List<string>() { name});
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

If you want to process a file:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string> result = IniToDictionary(File
  .ReadLines(@"c:\MyIniFile.ini"));
```

Let's have a look (at test input):

```
Console.Write(tring.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
  .Select(pair => $"{pair.Key,-15} : [{string.Join(", ", pair.Value)}]")));
```

**Outcome:**

```
core            : [bul_gravel_heli, ent_dst_concrete_large, bul_wood_splinter]
cut_armenian1   : [cs_arm2_muz_smg, cs_ped_foot_dusty]
```